# Spring JPA CriteriaBuilder not producing correct SQL

Tags: jpa, criteriabuilder

I have the following criteria builder statement:

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<TestEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(TestEntity.class);
    Root<TestEntity> itemRoot = criteriaQuery.from(TestEntity.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(itemRoot);

    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder.In inClause = criteriaBuilder.in(itemRoot.get("cost"));
    inClause.value(criteriaBuilder.literal(5.0d));

    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder.In inClause2 = criteriaBuilder.in(itemRoot.get("cost"));
    inClause2.value(criteriaBuilder.literal(5.0d));

    Predicate pred = criteriaBuilder.or(inClause, criteriaBuilder.and(inClause2, criteriaBuilder.like(itemRoot.get("name"), "%name%")));
    criteriaQuery.where(pred);
    TypedQuery typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    List<TestEntity> list = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Which produces the following sql :

```
select *
from test_entity testentity0_ 
where
    testentity0_.cost in (
        5.0
    ) 
    or (
        testentity0_.cost in (
            5.0
        )
    ) 
    and (
        testentity0_.name like ?
    )
```

but the where clause is wrong, i would expect the following :

```
select *
from test_entity testentity0_ 
where
    testentity0_.cost in (
        5.0
    ) 
    or (
        testentity0_.cost in (
            5.0
        )
        and (
            testentity0_.name like ?
        )
    )
```

The and is misplaced, it should go inside the second expression of the or statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both expressions are equivalent since `and` operator has precedence on `or`:

`A or B and C` is equivalent to `A or (B and C)`